# What does border mean in the glTexImage2D function?

Tags: opengl, border, glteximage2d

What is the `border` value of `glTexImage2D`? It's either 0 or 1. Does it decide whether this texture will have a border or not?

Where is the `border` values set?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the border value indicates whether the texture would have a border or not.

The border's color is defined by a call to `glTexParameter()`, with the `GL_TEXTURE_BORDER_COLOR` parameter. By default, it is black.

Note that the border color is only used when the texture is mapped using clamping (`GL_CLAMP` and similar) - a border doesn't make sense for a repeating pattern, and when linear interpolation is used for the texture data (`GL_LINEAR` and similar).

Also note that a texture border is not supported in the OpenGL ES variants of OpenGL (for embedded systems).

Comment: Modern desktop OpenGL versions also don't support texture borders: they generate `GL_INVALID_VALUE` if `border!=0`.